# Surjective, Invertible Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am working on the below problem:

Let $f: V \longrightarrow W$ be a surjective (onto) linear transformation between vector spaces $V$ and $W$. If $W$ is finite-dimensional, prove that there is a linear transformation $g: W \longrightarrow V$ with $f \circ g$ the identity map.

I'm struggling with this problem because we can't assume here that $V$ is finite-dimensional. If $V$ were finite-dimensional, the proof goes like this:

Choose a basis $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ for $V$. Then $fv_1,...,fv_n$ span the range of $T$, which, by surjectivity, is all of $W$. Thus, we reduce the list $fv_1, ... , fv_n$ to a basis for $W$. After possible reordering in this list, we may assume this basis is $fv_1, ... , fv_k$. Now, set $g(fv_i) = v_i$ for $i = 1,...,k$. Then for every basis vector $fv_i$, we have $(fg)(fv_i) = f(gfv_i) = fv_i$, so $fg$ is the identity map on this basis, hence $fg$ is the identity map on $W$.

How can I modify this proof, considering $V$ doesn't necessarily have to be finite-dimensional, by the statement of the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Pick a basis $(w_a)$ of $W$. Then, since $f$ is surjective...

Comment: Just for the avoidance of doubt, because the title of the question is misleading. The existence of such a $g$ does not prove that $f$ is invertible. $g$ is only a right inverse of $f$, and for $f$ to be invertible you need that it has a two-sided inverse. Take for example the map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that sends $(x,y) \mapsto x$. This is a surjective map between finite dimensional vector spaces but certainly is not invertible.

Comment: Also, the reason the question assumes finite dimensionality is to avoid consideration of the axiom of choice. The claim remains true if you drop the finite dimensional condition, but only if you assume the axiom of choice. The axiom of choice is used when you pick a basis of an infinite dimensional $W$, and to construct a function mapping onto said basis.